# href click area too wide

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I have a href on my page but it's waaay to wide and i've tried adding display:block's to it but it didn't help.

I have a lot of CSS so I think I shouldn't link my whole document, it's a mess.

I can give the link on which you might be able to test?

It's about the changing links under the slider on the frontpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
.cycle-slideshow a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**EDIT**: as pointed in the comments you have to override this behavior also in the pseudo-states (hover, focus and active). You can force that rule using `display: inline-block !important;` or with:

```
.cycle-slideshow a,
.cycle-slideshow a:focus,
.cycle-slideshow a:hover,
.cycle-slideshow a:active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @user3121076 you could need to add that behavior for `hover link and visited` states too +1

Answer (score 1):

The `display:block;` is what causes the problem because it extends them to 100% width. Remove the `display:block;` from the link-style and also from the `:hover-style`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem but then I realized I just forgot to close with an `</a>`tag